# ESLint Double Quotes in double quotes

Tags: javascript, string, lint

I am using ESLint to format my Javascript code. There I have the following piece of code:

`'<div id="' + sId + '" ';
...`

I get an ESLint warning telling me 'Strings should use double quotes', so I went ahead and changed the surrounding single quotes to double quotes and escaped the inner double quote. This lead to an ESLint error, which suggested I use the single quotes exactly as you see above.

Is there a way to solve this conflict so that I don't get the error or the warning? 
Info: I am stuck with ES5.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Escape double quotes in double-quoted strings (`"<div id=\"" + sId + "\" ";`)
- Turn off the linting rule which requires double-quoted strings
- Use a template literal instead (but that requires ES6 so you'd need to transpile it to ES5 afterwards)